How to set output rendering to Plain Text for errors?
I run pwsh scripts in a CI pipeline. I use $PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText' to ensure the results are returned in plain text. This works for general output, however, for some reason it isn't applying to errors thrown:
> throw "Some error"
[31;1mException: [0m
[31;1m[36;1mLine |[0m
[31;1m[36;1m[36;1m  17 | [0m [36;1mthrow "Some error"[0m
[31;1m[36;1m[36;1m[0m[36;1m[0m[36;1m     | [31;1m ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
[31;1m[36;1m[36;1m[0m[36;1m[0m[36;1m[31;1m[31;1m[36;1m     | [31;1mSome error[0m

How do I get errors to be rendered as plain text as well?
For context, I'm running this in OpenShift pipelines (Tekton), here is the entirety of the TaskRun code:
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TaskRun
metadata:
  name: test-output-rendering
spec:
  taskSpec:
    steps:
      - image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell
        script: |
          #!/usr/bin/env pwsh

          echo '> $PSStyle.OutputRendering = PlainText'
          $PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText'
          echo '> throw "Some error"'
          throw "Some error"

As an example, the OutputRendering setting is working correctly for normal output:
- image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell
  script: |
    #!/usr/bin/env pwsh

    echo '> Get-Item . | Format-List'
    Get-Item . | Format-List
    echo '> $PSStyle.OutputRendering = PlainText'
    $PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText'
    echo '> Get-Item . | Format-List'
    Get-Item . | Format-List

> Get-Item . | Format-List

    Directory: 

[32;1mName           : [0m/
[32;1mCreationTime   : [0m6/10/2024 10:00:55 PM
[32;1mLastWriteTime  : [0m6/10/2024 10:00:55 PM
[32;1mLastAccessTime : [0m6/10/2024 10:00:58 PM
[32;1mMode           : [0md-r--
[32;1mLinkType       : [0m
[32;1mTarget         : [0m

> $PSStyle.OutputRendering = PlainText
> Get-Item . | Format-List

    Directory: 

Name           : /
CreationTime   : 6/10/2024 10:00:55 PM
LastWriteTime  : 6/10/2024 10:00:55 PM
LastAccessTime : 6/10/2024 10:00:58 PM
Mode           : d-r--
LinkType       : 
Target         : 


I am unable to replicate this on the latest PowerShell.  Ensure you're using PowerShell v7.2+ with an xterm-compatible host.

@MaximilianBurszley this is the official microsoft powershell image so its v7.4.2 and I would imagine that it's xterm compatible

That is not a property of your image, but of whatever terminal/shell is running your image.  I would add some debug statements to ensure your automatic variable is set up correctly and that the powershell version of the image is correct.

I've verified that the automatic variable is working correctly and the version is 7.4.2. Please see my updated question.

I am unable to replicate your issue where you are still getting ANSI codes in exception output.

I too don't have an explanation, but one thing that you can try is to use a solution based on an environment variable that must be set before invoking PowerShell: set NO_COLOR to value 1.
